# Selecting users and changing Email Field in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am having an issue with this script. I am using it to look for certain users in an OU on AD and change the email address field to something I want. However, once I run the command, it chooses all of users with empty emails correctly, but seems to have replaced them all with the same email address, let's say "brubble@domain.com".

I need to target the ones with that email address now, and change them to the appropriate email address, but it just keeps changing it to "brubble@domain.com".

```
$SearchBase = "OU=Dead Accounts,DC=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=COM"
$Filter = {EmailAddress -notlike "*"}
get-ADUser -Filter $Filter -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties emailaddress | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.EmailAddress
    $newEmail = $_.samaccountname + "@esilicon.com"
    Set-Aduser $($_.SamAccountName) -EmailAddress $newEmail
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to work fine when i test it. Why this line `Write-Host $_.EmailAddress` which would output an empty line

Comment: It did work, but I think when I change EmailAddress -notlike "*" to something like EmailAddress -like "user" it may not be grabbing the correct items?

I can't really tell if it is not grabbing the correct users, or if it is still just substituting the email with the same one that was already there.

Comment: If you are trying to match a user just use `EmailAddress -eq "username@domain.com"`. If you are using like the in theory you should be using a wildcard like the following: `EmailAddress -like "*user*"`